# Land sales vs land sale vs sale of land

Tags: word-usage

Is the usage of "sale" correct in the following three sentences ?

1. Excluding extraordinary gain from sale of land, the company obtained a profit before tax of US$ 5 million.
2. Excluding extraordinary gain from land sale, the company obtained a profit before tax of US$ 5 million.
3. Excluding extraordinary gain from land sales, the company obtained a profit before tax of US$ 5 million.

Comment: Is your intention regarding "land sales" singular or plural?

Comment: I intend to say a singular land sale. But I understand that  sales also means "gross receipts", so in (3) does it mean profit from many activities of land sales or from the gross receipt of a single land sale ? Thanks

Comment: In an accounting context, there may be a general category "land sales" which you only have one item in, and still use the plural in reports.  I would use the third sentence when referring to a single sale only if it was common jargon to the intended audience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This is a valid construction, but you are extremely unlikely to encounter it outside of a business context. It is very much at home in an accounting filing, though, as seems to be the case here. *Sale of land* refers to the total aggregate gain from all sales of land during the fiscal reporting period. The phrase refers to selling land as a revenue producing activity in general, and not to any particular sales.
2. As it stands, this sentence is ungrammatical. *Land sale* is singular and should be either preceded with an article or pluralized (or both). If there was only one sale during the period in question, use *the land sale*. Since there was only one possible sale, it's understood exactly what's being discounted from the total, so use the definite article. If there were multiple sales, use *land sales*.
3. Use this if multiple land sales occurred during the time frame in question. You may optionally add *the* before *land sales*. The difference? Including *the* makes it understood which sales are referenced (the ones that took place during the accounting period in question). *Land sales* without an article means *any land sales*. It is also correct, but less formal, to use *land sales* to mean the same as in 1, but when doing so, do not use any article at all.

In the context of the example, all three meanings have the same effect: the before-tax profit does not include revenues generated by selling land. If no land sales took place, it would be nonsensical to call this out as being excluded from gross profit.

> I intend to say a singular land sale. But I understand that sales also means "gross receipts", so in (3) does it mean profit from many activities of land sales or from the gross receipt of a single land sale ?

Construction 1 uses the phrase in the sense of *gross receipts from a particular activity*, which many involve one, many, or even no individual sales. Version 2 means exactly one sale took place. Sentence 3 typically means that at least two sales occurred, though you can also use it in the sense of *gross receipts*, as in 1. In a technical, legal or fiduciary context, I would expect to encounter version 1 for this sense, though, because its meaning is unambiguous.

Because of the sentence structure and the fact that you are talking about a single sale only, I suggest using either 1 or 2, but not 3. 1 unambiguously means selling land as a general activity, and 2 specifies a single sale. 3 can be mistaken for meaning that multiple sales occurred. This also strikes me as being a more formal context, making 1 more appropriate than 3 if you want to talk about *gross receipts*.